# How to prevent TADORecordset from scrolling?

Tags: delphi, ado, recordset

I would like to prevent scrolling of ADORecordset basing on some condition.

For example it would be convenient to do something like that:

```
procedure TfrmMain.qryCenyBeforeScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if not (condition) then
    qryCeny.DoNotScroll;  //Just the idea
end;
```

How to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Are you trying to prevent the user from scrolling?

Comment: I have master-detail relationship but the detail recordset is in ltBatchOptimistic mode. If master recordset will change its position the detail recordset changes might be lost. If would like to show a confirmation window before scrolling the master recordset.

Comment: You could perhaps use an in-memory table for the master and detail and then you would have greater control over when to apply (or discard) any modifications

Comment: Yes, but what with posting data back do the database? I would have to use another component just for the insertions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could raise an exception, for example:

```
if not (condition) then
  Abort;
```